# OPENQUERY throws error when used with WIN2K8\SQL2K12

Tags: sql-server-2012, openquery

I'm trying the following Sql query to move my stored procedure result into table

```js
SELECT *
  INTO #tmpTable
FROM OPENQUERY(WIN2K8\SQL2K12, 'EXEC vcs_gauge  @gauge_name=vs1_bag,@first_rec_time=2014-09-01 09:00:00,@last_rec_time=2014-09-01 10:00:00')
```

following error is thrown, when I execute the query.

> Incorrect syntax near '\'.

I don't want to add linked server .How to resolve this issue?

**EDIT1**

When I do [win2k8\sql2k12], and first execute the following command

> EXEC sp_serveroption 'YourServer', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE

A new message comes

> **OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "WIN2K8\SQL2K12" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".**
>   Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Comment: OPENQUERY is used to execute sql against a linked server. The first parameter is the name of the linked server. Is `WIN2K8\ SQL2K12` the name of your linked server? If it really is then you need to use brackets `[WIN2K8\ SQL2K12]`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson after doing [WIN2K8\ SQL2K12],an error **Server 'WIN2K8\SQL2K12' is not configured for DATA ACCESS** is shown

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose DATETIME values in single quotes. And since your query is in a string itself, those single-quotes need to be doubled / escaped as follows (and you should probably also put the first parameter's value in escaped-single-quotes as it is clearly a string).

You should also fully qualify the stored procedure name with `[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].`.

And since the `vcs_gauge` proc uses Dynamic SQL, you need to specify the `WITH RESULT SETS` clause. For more info on this clause, please see the MSDN page for [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

```sql
SELECT *
INTO #tmpTable
FROM OPENQUERY([WIN2K8\SQL2K12],
             N'EXEC [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].vcs_gauge
                      @gauge_name = ''vs1_bag'',
                      @first_rec_time = ''2014-09-01 09:00:00'',
                      @last_rec_time = ''2014-09-01 10:00:00''
               WITH RESULT SETS ( { column_specification} );
             ');
```

Comment: **Msg 11529, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'vcs_gauge'.** ERROR is shown ,when I enclose datetime values with quotes as you mentioned.

Comment: @srutzly now following error comes **Msg 11514, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC ('WITH C AS
       ('+@query+')
      SELECT '+@column_str2+',Avg_Pressure,st1_ring_avg_press' in procedure 'vcs_gauge'  contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set**.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA Ok. That is a very specific error message. Have you done the suggestion? Due to that proc using dynamic SQL, your only option is to specify the `WITH RESULT SETS` clause.

Comment: I have not done the suggestion as I don't no how to use RESULT SET with SQl query and moreover I don't no all the datatypes of the columns which are retrieved from stored procedure.Is there some other way to fix it?

Comment: @SRY_JAVA I updated with a basic example and provided a link to the MSDN documentation. It is just a standard column + datatype list, just like `CREATE TABLE`. If you don't know the datatypes, can you temporarily update the proc to add an "INSERT INTO ##temp" just before the SELECT, then run it once, then run `EXEC tempdb.dbo.sp_help N'##temp';`?